# Redirect first time comments

Tags: comments, redirect, comments-template

So I want to add a comment redirect code to my comment form. I know I have this part right here:

```
<input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="http://domain.com/thank-you" />
```

So what I want to do is wrap that in an `if-else` to see if it's their first comment:

```
if ( $FirstTimeComment = true ) : ?>
    <input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="http://domain.com/thank-you" />
<?php endif;
```

I'm just not sure how to form the `if-else` to check if they are a first time commentator or not.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the comment form is generated *before* the comment is submitted that won't work too well logically.

The better option is `comment_post_redirect` filter:

```
/**
 * Filter the location URI to send the commenter after posting.
 *
 * @since 2.0.5
 *
 * @param string $location The 'redirect_to' URI sent via $_POST.
 * @param object $comment  Comment object.
 */
$location = apply_filters( 'comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment );
```

You can hook into it, check how many comments user has, and change the URL in `$location` as necessary.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you, but how do I check how many comments the user has (my initial question)?

Comment: The `$comment` passed should have all its data, you can fetch something like user's email out of it and use [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) to query how many are associated with it. Hadn't tried in code, just talking from the top of my head. :)